# Drag drop link into textbox with text only

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hyperlink, drag-and-drop

For example I have a link (or any other control that can be drag and drop) like below:

```
<a href="something.xxx" onclick="something">Text Link</a>
```

If I drag and drop this link into a textbox, it paste the link location into the textbox, but, I only want "Text Link", how can I do that?

Note that it needn't to be a link, I only need a web control that can be drag and drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with jQuery and jQuery UI:

```
$('a').draggable({revert: true});

$("#textbox").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
    }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/puzzlega/ffArQ/2/